# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') SEQUELIZE

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios, sequelize.js

I am working with React.js and Node.js and making calls to the Spotify API from the back.
In the front I pass an artist name, and the back responses the Albums, that's already done. I want to store each request (artist and date) in MySQL database, using sequelize, but each time I try there's the same error.

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')*

Here is my code:

**Model**

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, Model, DataTypes) => {
      class Request extends Model {}

      Request.init(
        {
          artist: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
          },
        },
        {
          sequelize,
          modelName: "request",
        },
      );

      return Request;
    };
```

**Model Index.js**

```
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_DATABASE, 
  process.env.DB_USERNAME, 
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD, 
  {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST, 
    dialect: process.env.DB_CONNECTION, 
    logging: false,
  },
);

const Request = require("./Request")(sequelize, Model, DataTypes);


module.exports = {
  sequelize,
  Request,
};
```

**DbSetup**

```
const db = require("./models");

module.exports = async () => {

  await db.sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  console.log("[Database] ¡Las tablas fueron creadas!");

};
```

**Controller**

```
const axios = require("axios");
const { Request } = require("../models/Request");

    async function storeArtist(req, res) {
      try {
        await Request.create({ artist: req.body.artist });
        res.json({message: "success"});
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
```

**React**

```
function SearchForm() {
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState("");
  const [artistInfo, setArtistInfo] = useState("");

  const handleSearch = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(artist);
    const response = await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8888/search-artist",
      data: {
        artist: artist,
      },
    });
    setArtistInfo(response.data);
    console.log(artistInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSearch} className=" my-5">
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label className="fs-4" id="form-label">
            DISCOVER YOUR NEW FAVOURITE ALBUM TODAY!{" "}
          </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            className="fs-5"
            id="artist"
            name="artist"
            value={artist}
            onChange={(ev) => setArtist(ev.target.value)}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Insert artist's name or group here.."
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button
          className="my-3 w-25 fs-5"
          variant="outline-success"
          type="submit"
        >
          Search Artist
        </Button>
      </Form>
      {!artistInfo && <p className="text-white">No artists found.</p>}
      {artistInfo && (
        <div>
          <div className="row g-4 text-center">
            <h1 className="text-white">
              {artistInfo.artist_info.artists.items[0].name}'s albums
            </h1>

            {artistInfo.albums_artist.items.map((album) => (
              <ul
                /*   key={artistInfo.id} */
                className="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-around"
              >
                <li>
                  <img
                    className="img-fluid img-album"
                    src={album.images[0].url}
                    alt={artistInfo.artist_info.artists.items[0].name}
                  />
                  <p className="text-white my-5 ">{album.name}</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}

export default SearchForm;
```

Any ideas why this might be happening or how can I find a solution? I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const { Request } = require("../models")` (ie imported from `index.js`)?